# Using old PC as NAS

Tags: linux, nas

I have extra P4 PC (Dell Dimension 2400). And I would like to use this PC as NAS. Any advise? What is the best way to make NAS from a PC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to deck it out with hard drives.  If possible, try to suit the computer to use eSATA hard drives or SCSI hard drives and set them up in a RAID array to add a level of security and redundancy to your information.  Which level of RAID you choose depends on what type of redundancy and error checking you want.

Then you need the software.  [FreeNAS](http://freenas.org) is an excellent option.  Depending on how much RAM the box has, you might want to set it up as an Internet-enabled NAS.  This could give you access to your music, pictures, and documents across any network connection.  Think about it more like a personal cloud server, and less as just a NAS.

Comment: +1 for FreeNAS. It's the only thing you need for a NAS, besides the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

[FreeNAS](http://freenas.org) is an option.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at [OpenFiler](http://www.openfiler.com/) and it's pretty solid. Linux based.